# LibreOffice swriter command line to convert PDF but want landscape option

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, cups

I am using libreOffice on CentOS to convert rtf and html to PDF using:

> swriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export doc_file.doc

all is working great but I cannot find any command line option to change the pdf from portrait to landscape.

Is that even an option?

Comment: Do I need to install CUPS-PDF to achieve that if I need landscape or I can use command line in libreoffice?

Answer (score 2):

You can use unoconv with a template (.ott) that has the page style set to landscape.

More info about [unoconv](http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.com.co/2012/01/unoconv-is-number-one.html).